# Function not returning expected value for one specific case

Tags: c

I am new to this and this is only my 2nd semester of C.  The code compiles fine.  It does most of what it is supposed to.  For some reason, when the lowest value in the `temp[]` array is in the first element, the `min` function returns a zero.  In fact the variable (`lo`) is set to 0. The function `hiTemp` doesn't have the same problem but it is almost the same code, just a sign change.

```
#include <stdio.h>

//prototype functions

float avgTemp(float deg[], int size);

float hiTemp(float deg[], int size);

float loTemp(float deg[], int size);

//main
void main(void)
{
    char* day[] = {"first", "second", "third", "fourth", "fifth", "sixth", "seventh"};
    float temp[7] = {0};
    int i = 0;
    float avg = 0;
    float hi = 0;
    float lo = 0;

    //Do/while loop to collect the temps for the days of the week
    do
    {
        printf("Enter the temp for the %s day:", day[i]);

        scanf("%f", &temp[i]);

        i++;
    }
    while(i <= 6);

    //math and print for the average temp

    avg = avgTemp(temp, 7);

    hi = hiTemp(temp, 7);

    lo = loTemp(temp, 7);

    printf("The high temp was %.2f\n", hi);

    printf("The low temp was %.2f\n", lo);

    printf("The average temp is %.2f\n", avg);

    if(hi > 113)
        puts("The high temperature is out of range");

    if(lo < -4)
        puts("The low temperature is out of range");
}

//function to find the average
float avgTemp(float deg[], int size)
{
    float add = 0;

    for(size; size >= 0; size--)
        add = add + deg[size];

    return add / 7;
}

//function to find the hi temp
float hiTemp(float deg[], int size)
{
    float hi = 0;

    int i = 1;

    for(i = 1; i <= size; i++)
    {
        if(deg[0] <= deg[i])
            deg[0] = deg[i];
    }

    hi = deg[0];

    return hi;
}

//function to find the lo temp
float loTemp(float deg[], int size)
{
    float lo = 0;

    for(size; size > 0; size--)
    {
        if(deg[size] <= deg[7])
            deg[7] = deg[size];
    }

    lo = deg[7];

    printf("debug lo:%f\n",lo);

    return lo;
}
```

Comment: Why the hard coded magic number `7` in `loTemp`?

Comment: @Downvoter: Don't downvote without specifying a good reason. Do not discourage people who are just learning stackoverflow and C when they have a valid question.

Comment: You might like to debug your code, using a debugger: http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Also attending some lectures on algorithms might be a good idea .. .;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `loTemp()` you use `deg[7]` incorrectly. `deg[7] = deg[size];` overwrites memory which is not yours. You have 7 items, indexes from 0 to 6. Use an extra variable for this purpose... such as `lo` which was declared for this purpose. Also, do not read from `deg[7]`.

Also, please note that in `hiTemp()` you lose the first value of the array, due to the fact that you use `deg[0]` as a helper variable. Use `hi` which was declared with this purpose.

Also same issue for `hiTemp()`, accessing elments `0` to `size`, that is accessing `size+1` elements, which can not be ok if the array had been declared to have only `size` elements.

Also the same issue for `avgTemp` ... you again access one extra byte out of your bounds.

Comment: More or less the same issue for `hiTemp()`, accessing elements `0` to `size`, that is accessing `size+1` elements, which can **not** be ok if the array had been declared to have only `size` elements.

Comment: @alk Correct observation. Modified the answer (i.e.: copied your comment into it :) ) ... but let's admit it ... we all were beginners at some stage :) and in those days there was no stackoverflow.

Comment: And modified it again ... :)